# Query works when executed on kibana, but doesn't when executed in Spring with StringQuery

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl, spring-data-elasticsearch

Elasticsearch and Kibana: 8.5.3
Spring boot:3.0.5
spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch:3.0.5
Spring Data Elasticsearch: 5.0.4
Code:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {

    private final ProductRepository productRepository;

    private final ElasticsearchOperations operations;

    public PageableProductsDTO searchProducts(String name, String category, String subcategory, String brands,
                                              Integer page, Integer size, Integer priceMin, Integer priceMax,
                                              Boolean searchDescription) {
        var queryBuilder = buildQueryString(name, category, subcategory, brands, priceMin, priceMax);
        System.out.println(queryBuilder.toString());
        var query = new StringQuery(queryBuilder.toString(), PageRequest.of(page, size));
        SearchHits<Product> searchHits = operations.search(query, Product.class, IndexCoordinates.of("product"));
        var productDtos = searchHits.stream().map(SearchHit::getContent)
                .map(ProductServiceImpl::mapToProductDto).toList();
        return new PageableProductsDTO(productDtos, (int) (Math.ceil(((double) (searchHits.getTotalHits() / size)))));
    }

    private static StringBuilder buildQueryString(String name, String category, String subcategory, String brands, Integer priceMin, Integer priceMax) {
        var isFirst = false;
        var queryBuilder = new StringBuilder("""
                {"bool": {
                      "filter": [""");
        if (category != null) {
            if (!isFirst)
            {
                isFirst= true;
            }
            queryBuilder.append("{\n" +
                    "          \"term\": {\n" +
                    "            \"category\": \"" + category + "\"\n" +
                    "          }\n" +
                    "        }");
        }

        if (subcategory != null) {
            if (!isFirst)
            {
                isFirst= true;
            }else {
                queryBuilder.append(",");
            }
            queryBuilder.append("{\n" +
                    "          \"term\": {\n" +
                    "            \"subcategory\": \"" + subcategory + "\"\n" +
                    "          }\n" +
                    "        }");
        }
        if (priceMax != null && priceMin != null) {
            if (!isFirst)
            {
                isFirst= true;
            }else {
                queryBuilder.append(",");
            }
            queryBuilder.append("{\n" +
                    "          \"range\": {\n" +
                    "            \"price\": {\n" +
                    "              \"gte\":" + priceMin + ",\n" +
                    "              \"lte\": " + priceMax + "\n" +
                    "            }\n" +
                    "          }\n" +
                    "        }");
        }
        if (name != null) {
            if (!isFirst)
            {
                isFirst= true;
            }else {
                queryBuilder.append(",");
            }
            queryBuilder.append("{\n" +
                    "          \"wildcard\": {\n" +
                    "            \"name\": {\n" +
                    "              \"value\":\"*" + name + "*\",\n" +
                    "              \"case_insensitive\":true\n" +
                    "            }\n" +
                    "          }\n" +
                    "        }");
        }
        if (brands != null) {
            if (!isFirst)
            {
                isFirst= true;
            }else {
                queryBuilder.append(",");
            }
            var brandsFilter = Arrays.stream(brands.split(","))
                    .map(item -> "\"" + item + "\"")
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
            queryBuilder.append("{\n" +
                    "          \"terms\": {\n" +
                    "            \"brand\": [" + brandsFilter + "]}\n" +
                    "        }");
        }
        queryBuilder.append("""
                ]
                    }
                  }
                """);
        return queryBuilder;
    }
}
```

PagableProductDTO:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategies.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
public final class PageableProductsDTO {
    private List<ProductDTO> products;
    private Integer NumberOfPages;

}
```

index mapping:

```
{
  "product": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "_class": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "index": false,
          "doc_values": false
        },
        "brand": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "category": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "description": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "english"
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "image_url": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "price": {
          "type": "float"
        },
        "stock": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "subcategory": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

query created with code:

```
{"bool": {
      "filter": [{
          "term": {
            "category": "Electronics"
          }
        },{
          "term": {
            "subcategory": "Smartphones"
          }
        },{
          "range": {
            "price": {
              "gte":20,
              "lte": 1000
            }
          }
        },{
          "wildcard": {
            "name": {
              "value":"*iphone*",
              "case_insensitive":true
            }
          }
        },{
          "terms": {
            "brand": ["Apple"]}
        }]
    }
  }
```

it returns this in code:

```
{
    "products": [],
    "number_of_pages": 0
}
```

In kibana I made a couple of modifications to make the query work in kibana:

```
GET product/_search
{
  "query":{"bool": {
          "filter": [{
              "term": {
                "category": "Electronics"
              }
            },{
              "term": {
                "subcategory": "Smartphones"
              }
            },{
              "range": {
                "price": {
                  "gte":20,
                  "lte": 1000
                }
              }
            },{
              "wildcard": {
                "name": {
                  "value":"*iphone*",
                  "case_insensitive":true
                }
              }
            },{
              "terms": {
                "brand": ["Apple"]}
            }]
        }
      }
}
```

I get this response:

```
{
  "took": 4,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 3,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "product",
        "_id": "j4QHPogB-yN3XaabZkmS",
        "_score": 0,
        "_source": {
          "id": "1220fa2e-4f81-4504-9c43-651e1f0d03e1",
          "brand": "Apple",
          "category": "Electronics",
          "subcategory": "Smartphones",
          "name": "iPhone 13 Pro",
          "price": 565.9,
          "stock": 735,
          "image_url": "https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=755",
          "description": "This iPhone 13 Pro from Apple is the ideal choice for anyone who demands the best performance and features. With its large screen, this iPhone 13 Pro will exceed all your expectations and make your life easier."
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "product",
        "_id": "qoQHPogB-yN3XaabZkmS",
        "_score": 0,
        "_source": {
          "id": "1400c5cc-efde-4367-8f1d-9abc62542ff8",
          "brand": "Apple",
          "category": "Electronics",
          "subcategory": "Smartphones",
          "name": "iPhone XR",
          "price": 865.27,
          "stock": 613,
          "image_url": "https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=834",
          "description": "This iPhone XR from Apple is the ideal choice for anyone who demands the best performance and features. With its responsive touchpad, this iPhone XR will exceed all your expectations and make your life easier."
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "product",
        "_id": "tIQHPogB-yN3XaabZ0s5",
        "_score": 0,
        "_source": {
          "id": "0007d3aa-b614-4d78-bbac-7827ed63599f",
          "brand": "Apple",
          "category": "Electronics",
          "subcategory": "Smartphones",
          "name": "iPhone 13 Pro",
          "price": 832.73,
          "stock": 433,
          "image_url": "https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=778",
          "description": "Get ready for the ultimate iPhone 13 Pro experience with Apple. With its lightweight design, this iPhone 13 Pro is the perfect choice for anyone who loves to stay connected and entertained on the go."
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

EDIT: Product class:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Document(indexName = "product", versionType = Document.VersionType.INTERNAL)
public class Product {

    @Id
    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String id;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String brand;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String name;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Float)
    private Float price;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String category;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String subcategory;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword, name = "image_url")
    private String imageURL;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Long)
    private Long stock;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text, analyzer = "english")
    private String description;
}
```

Comment: How is `Product` defined?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch I added the Product class.

Comment: I figured it out. I tried get page 1 of size 100 when I only had 8 hits and that is why it didn't work. Pages start from 0. Thanks for the help @P.J.Meisch.

Comment: Glad you found, an I didn't do anything